# What is the meaning of 关心种子?

Tags: meaning

I was watching a YouTube video, and the guy in the very beginning said "关心种子" means: a type of species desperate for attention. Is that true?

Here is the video for reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jv_WYLb_WMY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an Internet Language. This is a good explanation.

> “在博取关注的方面是种子选手”→“关心种子”→“关种”

I think you know what it means by seeing the YouTube Video.

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't know what category to place it in, haha. Internet Language, thanks ~ :)

Answer (score 1):

This phrase doesn't make any sense to me. I have never used it or heard any Mandarin speaker use it. (I'm a native speaker of Chinese.)

Comment: Thank you for taking time to write! Could you check out the YouTube video I linked, the guy said that phrase within the first minute of the video.. just trying to understand if it's a real phrase - haha